# How to add cell data to HTTP request and move to the next cell

Tags: excel, vba, http

I am trying to send a `POST` request through vba and need to have the variable cheese go to the next cell and present that cells data in the url. Am I on the right track, and how would I go about making this happen?

I tried to make a loop function that would add to the cell variable already.

```
Sub markExportOrders()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
   pepperjack = pepperjack + 1
   Cheese = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & pepperjack).Value
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   i = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
     i = i + 1
     URL = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Orders( " & Cheese & ")/Export?access_token=xxxxxxx"
     objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
     objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     objHTTP.send
     pepperjack = pepperjack + 1
   Loop

End Sub
```

I should be able to run the macro and then call a get request with `exported=true` and the order numbers that were in the excel sheet will be in the list.

Comment: Always helps to describe the *specific* problem you're having when running your code.  You never change the value of `Cheese` in your loop. And this looks like a GET request (you are sending the information in the URL vs. a POST (which would use `objHTTP.send urlEncodednformationHere`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the objHTTP.send? I have changed Cheese so that it is the active cell and it offsets at the end of the loop moving to the next cell. However, I believe that it is not posting, could you help explain more on that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp